# How to set virtual path on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a website witch all webpages are in a folder called Pages. So in order to access the web pages, the URLs are website/Pages/mypage.aspx.

So far no problem.

My question is: what if I want a virtual folder? for example, I want when somebody enters the URL www.website.com/mypage it redirects to website/Pages/mypage.aspx

I'm trying to use the virtual applications and directories option on azure configurations, but when I try to access, it says the directory doesn't exists.
my configuration is:

**virtual path:** /acessovip 
**physical path:** site\wwwroot\Pages\acessovip

is this the correct way to link the acessovip.aspx page?

Comment: That's not a virtual folder. That's a concept called [routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd329551(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: "Virtual directories" in IIS are a distinct and separate concept from URI Routing.

Comment: So I can't do what I'm trying to do? The way I see... I would have to create another webapp?